# When is type coercion a good idea?

Tags: javascript, type-casting

When do you want (on purpose) to coerce type in JavaScript? I mean, beyond comparing strings and numbers, when does it benefit something you're building?

Examples of type coercion:

```
"The answer is " + 42 
//=> "The answer is 42"

"37" - 7 
//=> 30

"37" + 7 
//=> "377"

var foo = [0];
console.log(foo == foo);
//=> true

console.log(foo == !foo);
//=> true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental principle that most affects type coercion is **be liberal in what you accept**.  For a language with argument types are part of a function signature, you could handle, say, a `log` function by requiring `string` parameters and having overloads for `object` and `integer` and whatnot.

In JavaScript, which is so loosely typed that you should treat function arguments as simply a naming suggestion for the first X arguments passed, type coercion can be used to help quickly handle most argument types.  And, of course, it's a fundamental aspect of feature inspection.  Consider the following, which will take any number of arguments and pass them to `console.log` as a single space-seperated string:

```
function toLog() {
    if(arguments.length && window.console && window.console.log) {
        var ArgString = "";
        for(var a = 0; a < arguments.length; a++) {
            ArgString += arguments[a];
        }
        console.log(ArgString);
    }
}
```

The above uses type coercion in three ways that are extremely useful for JavaScript:

1. The `arguments.length` property is coerced from a number to a boolean value to see if there are elements in the [arguments pseudo-array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).
2. Both the global `console` object and its `log` method are coerced from objects to boolean if they are not null, which prevents an (old?) IE bug where `console.log` would cause errors if called without the developer console open.
3. By setting `ArgString` to an empty string `""` on initialization, we signal to the interpreter to coerce all arguments to strings as well.  Which isn't all that useful on a modern browser, but works for the sake of our example.